# Rename Jenkins 2.0 pipeline steps

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

During or after a build, if I go to my pipeline's view page,

http://myJenkinsInstance:8080/view/All/job/ios/1/flowGraphTable/

I get quite non-descriptive build steps, which aren't that easy to know what's happening underneath, for instance,

[image: jenkins view]

Whereas we're actually running something like,

```
sh 'rake build package'
```

Or,

```
archiveArtifacts 'packages/*.*'
```

Instead of "Shell Script" or "General Build Step", is there any way to rename these to be like what's actually happening, instead of these generic names?